# DNN / WebMatrix / Localhost / Multiple Sites

Tags: dotnetnuke, webmatrix

It seems that DNN is undergoing an upgrade and I cannot access the forums or many of the docs. Needing an answer soon, and Google providing too many varied types of hits (none of which are helpful or most of which post to the DNN site that is undergoing that upgrade), I had a few questions about setting up DNN.

First, I am coming from Orchard. There I was able to use Webmatrix - I downloaded the web version, opened as administrator, created modules, messed with themes, etc. Using the Orchard Docs, I was able to set up a multi-tenant site and run it on local host (IIS express through Webmatrix) - this included modifying the host/config files to view the multi-tenant sites.  I could then publish to my own server running IIS 7. On the server I set up the landlord site then bound the tenants with no problem.

Being new to DNN (and things not being readily available at the moment on their site), I was hoping I could get some guidance on how to set up DNN similar to what I did with Orchard.

First question is obviously whether or not that is possible (i.e., no IIS, only IIS Express (Webmatrix) on my local machine).

Here would be my other questions:

1. If I can run it locally, can I just download the 7.1.0 new install package, and open Webmatrix (as Admin) on the folder I unzipped it in?
2. Assuming I just "Run" the website, I will then set up the "Landlord" instance of DNN on the following screens, correct? (i.e., where it asks for credentials and what DB setup I can use)
3. Can I then go ahead and create sub-tenant sites (alias/portal)? If so, do I go about manually updating my host/config files to run those tenants (depending on the port)?
4. Assume all of the above is correct, do I have to "reinstall" the 7.1.0 package on my webserver, or will a simple publish from Webmatrix do (with the proper credentials in Settings)? If so, I can handle pointing to the landlord on my server and then binding my subtenants in IIS.

Sorry for the n00b questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the [Download page](http://www.dnnsoftware.com/Community/Download) on dnnsoftware.com, there's a link to click which will start the install process within WebMatrix: http://www.microsoft.com/web/gallery/install.aspx?appsxml=www.microsoft.com%2fweb%2fwebpi%2f2.0%2fWebApplicationList.xml&appid=106

When you create a new portal, you can specify that it uses a URL which is a subdirectory of the current URL (i.e. a child portal alias), so that you don't have to use different ports.  I'm not especially familiar with IIS Express, so I would expect that you could point multiple ports to the site, and map those as different portal aliases, but not sure exactly how you could do that, if you don't want to make use of child portal aliases.

To publish a site, you should just need to push the file system and database, and setup IIS.